# How do I kill a DNN scheduled task?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am writing a scheduled task that on a particular server won't stop running, even though my logs tell me it isn't doing any more work (I don't see any errors/exceptions either).  How do I kill the process short of restarting IIS?

I should mention I've tried killing the w3wp.exe process, but that hasn't worked (so it must be a different process, but I'm not sure which process it is and haven't had any luck finding it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that the completion is never recorded, but the job isn't running anymore. Even after a website recycle you'll see the ticker still count. I wouldn't worry about it too much unless the job itself isn't starting up again as it should be on the schedule that is set.